# how to get log of agi in asterisk with pystrix?

Tags: python, asterisk, agi

how to log my pystrix agi line by line?
I set "try,except Exception" for this solution, but don't complete.
I want to get full log of pystrix agi line by line!
how to log my agi with pystrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is pystrix, but you can get agi log of ANY call by using

```
asterisk -r
agi set debug on
```